# Ubuntu one stuck on "File Sync Starting" due to IPCerror on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sync

NOTE TO EDITORS/Moderators: This issue has *not been solved* (or rather explained) in a way that is intelligible and useful to a non-Linux-geek in anyone of the postings concering this issue (I read them all).

Here is my problem:

FILE SYNC STOPPED DUE TO IPC ERROR

Ubuntone worked fine on my Ubuntu 12.04 system for a week (I am an Ubuntu beginner). Thereafter "Filesync is starting" showed with no further response for hours. I tried repeatedly. At times the following error message appeared (not exact wording):

> "Sorry, an error occurred and Ubuntuone needs to close" with
>
> "Details": "IPCerror" (No further explanation of the error.)

Please provide guidelines that don't require Linux coding knowledge to understand and handle, and *please use plain simple english* and not an idioma that requires knowledge of Linux abbreviations etc.

Comment: Contact Ubuntu One support at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ about your issue.

Comment: While contacting Ubuntu One is a good idea here, I don't see why this is off-topic. We support Ubuntu One here.